# Using jQuery to update multiple objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a profile page where I render all of the user's lists using a partial:

users/show.html.erb

```
<%= render @lists %>
```

For each list I show how many wishes are associated:

lists/_list.html.erb

```
<p class="muted" id="wishes_count"><%= pluralize(list.wishes.count, "wish") %></p>
```

I'm using drag and drop to allow the user to move wishes from one list to another using jQuery sortable.

Right now, I'm using the following code:

wishes.js.erb

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.user_list_wishes').sortable({
   connectWith: ".user_list_wishes",
   items: ".user_list_wish",
   placeholder: "sortable_placeholder",
   update: function(e, ui)
   {
      if (this === ui.item.parent()[0]) 
      {
        item_id = ui.item.data('item-id');
        list_id = $(this).data('list-id');
        position = ui.item.index();
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: $(this).data('update-url'),
          dataType: 'json',
          data: { id: item_id, wish: { row_order_position: position, list_id: list_id } }
        }),
        $("#wishes_count").html('<%= pluralize(list.wishes.count, "wish") %>')
      }
    }
  })
})
```

This line of code:

```
$("#wishes_count").html('<%= pluralize(list.wishes.count, "wish") %>')
```

makes my application throw a `NoMethodError` `undefined method 'wishes' for nil:NilClass`

I believe it has something to do with how I render lists and reference them individually in my javascript?

Any suggestions on how to solve this problem is much appreciated!

Comment: In your business logic, is it possible that list.wishes is `nil`?

Comment: Well, I guess it is, since users can move wishes around and they might end up with no wishes in a particular list?

Comment: You are correct, it is possible that `list.wishes` is `nil`, however `<%= pluralize(list.wishes.count, "wish") %>` handles this by rendering "0 wishes". I believe it has something to do with how I render lists and reference them individually in my javascript?

Comment: Actually, I looked at your error again. In your case, `list` itself was `nil`. Is that possible?

Comment: No, that's not possible

Comment: Clearly, `NoMethodError undefined method 'wishes' for nil:NilClass` indicates that `list` was `nil`, so you need to check how it came to be.

Comment: Could it be because I'm not referencing list correctly? Notice, I'm using `@lists` to call a partial `_list.html.erb`

Answer (score 0):

You must handle the scenario where `list` is null using the following condition:

```
$("#wishes_count").html('<%= pluralize(list ? list.wishes.count : 0, "wish") %>')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem could be in your `render` call - according to the [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials):

> If you have an instance of a model to render into a partial, you can use a shorthand syntax:
>
> ```
> <%= render @customer %>
> ```
>
> Assuming that the @customer instance variable contains an instance of the Customer model, this will use _customer.html.erb to render it and will pass the local variable customer into the partial which will refer to the @customer instance variable in the parent view.

So check that this is the case - do you have a partial called `_lists.html.erb` and a parent variable called `list`?

Comment: The lists are rendered perfectly. I'm using collection (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-collections) using `@lists` as parent variable and a partial `_list.html.erb`. I think the problem is how I reference lists in `$("#wishes_count").html('<%= pluralize(list.wishes.count, "wish") %>')`

Comment: if that's the case, then `list` is `nil` so...must be a problem with js.  but i don't know that much about js!  sorry!